# OS X 10.4 Server, adding an email user on the command line

Tags: ssh, virtualhost, email, mac-osx-server, terminal

I have an XServe running OS X 10.4 Server. Is it possible to add a new email user from a terminal (I only have SSH access normally)? Also, is it possible to add a new mail virtual host from the terminal?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well a google for `osx server adduser` gets me to this page about a script to [add users to your OSX server on the command line](http://www.afp548.com/article.php?story=20040813023740511).

This serverfault question [details setting up mail virtual hosts on osx via the gui](https://serverfault.com/questions/180686/hosting-multiple-domains-on-mac-os-x-server).  Since OSX server runs postfix, I suspect you could set up virtual email domains by editing the postfix config as [shown here](http://www.akadia.com/services/postfix_separate_mailboxes.html) with proper editing of your `main.cf`.

Comment: script didn't work, kept saying 'missing DS reference or node', but the postfix tip helped. Thanks.